# Spring Integration DSL: How can I set the logging.level to DEBUG for .log()

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How can I change the `logging.level` to a level below `INFO` for the `.log()` entries ? By default, it seems to log only `INFO` and above. I'm unable to get it to log `DEBUG` and `TRACE`.

I have tried (in application.yml):

```
logging.level:
  org.springframework.integration: DEBUG
  com.my.namespace: DEBUG
```

but so far no success. Setting the logging.level for `org.springframework.integration` to DEBUG does indeed log a whole bunch of DEBUG stuff, but not my own `.log()` statements.

**UPDATE:**: I am using `.log()` like this:

```
.log(DEBUG, "some category", m -> "print something using: " + m.getPayload())
```

But when I set the log level to DEBUG, nothing is printed. Only if I use INFO like this:

```
.log(INFO, "some category", m -> "print something using: " + m.getPayload())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log()` operator is fully based on the `LoggingHandler`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#logging-channel-adapter and it is implemented like this:

```
public B log() {
    return log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO);
}
```

So, it is an `INFO` independently of what you have so far in the config.

So, if you'd like to change some `log()` operator defaults, you should consider to some its appropriate alternative like the same variant where you can provide a desired level:

```
public B log(LoggingHandler.Level level) {
```

It can be done via eternal configuration, but it is possible only via custom property and some conversion logic like `LoggingHandler.Level.valueOf(level.toUpperCase())`.

**UPDATE**

To make it visible in logs you must provide that  `org.springframework.integration: DEBUG` because this one is a default category for the `LoggingHandler`. Or use different `log()` variant:

log(LoggingHandler.Level level, String category)

For example:

```
log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "my.category")
```

and provide that category in your logging config. Otherwise it is going to rely on default (root?) level.

So, according your code in the question it must be like this:

```
logging.level:
  com.my.namespace: DEBUG
```

---

```
.log(DEBUG, "com.my.namespace", m -> "print something using: " + m.getPayload())
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using .log(DEBUG) already. But it's not getting logged. log(INFO) gets output but log(DEBUG) doesn't.

Comment: I added an example to my question above to make it clearer how I am actually using `.log()`.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thank You. I had somehow missed that.